# Convert Query in laravel with NOT IN CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

i have a query that works in navicat . I want to convert it in laravel but i got errors. Please help me to convert this query to Laravel Query Builder.

Here is the regular query in Navicat:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
assign_sec
WHERE   assign_sec.stud_id 
    NOT IN (SELECT stud_id FROM attendance WHERE attendance.att_date="2018-01-03" AND attendance.att_sec = "10") 
    AND assign_sec.sec_id = "10"
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laravel, for complex query you can try `RAW Expression` like:

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("Your query here") );
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions)